# Best way to display large HTML string in a HTML div

Tags: html, asp.net-core-mvc

I have string which `10558` characters long contains HTML Markup like:

```
<html>
  <body>
   .......
   .......
   .......
  </body>
</html>
```

I am fetching that using AJAX call.

What I want is, to show that HTML markup in a  element on MVC page,

I tried with `200` characters string which works fine but when it comes to `10558` characters then the window gets hanged.

What is the best way to show the large HTML markup in div?

Comment: 10K is a lot but not weird.

Comment: If your just outputting using razor this should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You said you're getting the HTML from an AJAX call - as opposed to rendering it server-side using Razor).

If you want to show the markup so that human users can "see" the HTML syntax, then set `.textContent`:

```
var htmlFromAjax = ...
var e = document.createElement("pre");
e.textContent = htmlFromAjax;
document.body.appendChild( e );
```

If you actually want to render the HTML *as* HTML inside the document, then using `innerHTML` is acceptable for this task - assuming you fully-trust the source of the AJAX response not to return malicious HTML that might contain scripts (and regardless, [you should set a `Content-Security-Policy` on your document so browsers won't execute any added scripts anyway](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/disable-inline-javascript-for-security/)):

```
var htmlFromAjax = ...
var div = document.createElement("div");
e.innerHTML = htmlFromAjax;
document.body.appendChild( e );
```

Comment: I want to display that inside `<td>` so I created element and added it to td element which works but is shows text of all html tags.

Answer (score 1):

This is 10K - nothing special

If you want to see the markup, replace all `<` with `&lt;`

```html
<div id="Inner">



  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <h4>"Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit..."</h4>
  <h5>"There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."</h5>


  <hr>

  <div id="Content">
    
    <div class="boxed">
      
      <div id="lipsum">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec euismod nulla sit amet feugiat facilisis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Duis felis magna, faucibus non blandit id, luctus quis ante. Ut posuere felis neque,
          ut semper turpis rhoncus et. Vivamus convallis erat sed nisl dignissim posuere. Morbi hendrerit mattis quam at scelerisque. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Integer congue ligula nec arcu
          venenatis consectetur. Suspendisse id quam finibus, semper lorem sit amet, elementum augue. Praesent facilisis volutpat nisi, at vehicula arcu imperdiet ut. Cras viverra sit amet nulla ut porta. Suspendisse tempus accumsan ligula quis gravida.
        </p>
        <p>
          Proin non faucibus ligula. Donec aliquam dapibus tellus, eget feugiat eros laoreet vel. Ut convallis, magna a luctus sodales, massa nisl cursus justo, eget ornare dolor purus nec ligula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras non porta dui. Vivamus at
          iaculis eros. Integer vestibulum risus et nisi congue, eu auctor diam consectetur. Duis hendrerit tristique quam quis vehicula.
        </p>
        <p>
          Nulla placerat scelerisque tellus, eget tempor purus vehicula eget. Nunc dictum ipsum a laoreet fermentum. Sed id nulla ut sapien tincidunt faucibus. Sed pretium placerat lorem vitae pharetra. Curabitur libero est, euismod molestie est sit amet, dapibus
          accumsan libero. Aliquam eget facilisis ante. Fusce et nibh at nisl semper egestas ut at augue. Sed quam augue, tristique et rutrum ut, consectetur sed dolor. In ultricies odio eget erat pharetra vestibulum. Donec blandit, tortor eget molestie
          sollicitudin, odio quam feugiat arcu, sed ullamcorper purus felis et felis. Nullam mattis consectetur orci, egestas feugiat orci tristique eu. Nunc convallis felis id ex ornare, sed vestibulum mi tempor. Donec sodales eros sit amet nibh tempus
          tristique.
        </p>
        <p>
          Morbi non sapien nibh. Curabitur vel velit eget lectus consectetur imperdiet. Proin suscipit nulla mauris, vel mattis sem porttitor quis. Ut sit amet convallis arcu, non eleifend felis. Phasellus porta scelerisque lacus, vel consectetur nunc convallis
          eget. Pellentesque pellentesque lobortis nisl et porta. Aenean fermentum et enim ac volutpat. Suspendisse aliquet, mi ut ullamcorper elementum, orci ligula vehicula lacus, lobortis lacinia lacus mi ut augue. Aliquam varius nec sapien fermentum
          sollicitudin. Aliquam auctor odio et est ultricies bibendum in vel elit.
        </p>
        <p>
          Phasellus a consequat lectus. Aenean nisi eros, fringilla id libero at, elementum rhoncus magna. Donec ullamcorper blandit nunc non dapibus. Aenean ornare commodo lorem at convallis. Nam eros eros, volutpat non scelerisque eu, blandit ac elit. Nulla facilisi.
          Curabitur id dignissim elit, ultricies vulputate risus.
        </p>
        <p>
          Nunc ac orci a elit rutrum semper. Vestibulum in commodo erat. Nam iaculis congue euismod. Phasellus laoreet nibh non mauris condimentum vulputate. Donec eget diam porta, eleifend leo vitae, pellentesque turpis. Quisque suscipit dictum nibh pellentesque
          sollicitudin. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        </p>
        <p>
          Integer neque felis, dictum eget neque eget, rutrum vestibulum sapien. Sed erat elit, convallis in sem et, efficitur cursus lacus. Etiam tempor leo sapien, eu placerat arcu lobortis ac. Donec dapibus ullamcorper lectus ac facilisis. Vestibulum facilisis,
          odio ac mollis sollicitudin, nibh massa pharetra odio, vitae pharetra metus nibh quis urna. Nulla nunc risus, dictum id placerat quis, accumsan feugiat augue. Aliquam quis efficitur tortor. Quisque varius felis eros, id consectetur enim porta
          quis.
        </p>
        <p>
          Nam id purus vitae nulla placerat commodo. Cras faucibus vehicula lectus ac pharetra. Aenean id elit ut risus ultrices ullamcorper sit amet convallis dui. Donec facilisis, leo quis ultricies fermentum, massa urna sagittis turpis, non tempus erat diam
          eget enim. Morbi mauris leo, pulvinar eu aliquam eget, lacinia sit amet mauris. Donec blandit mollis nunc nec maximus. Donec at lacinia ligula, a euismod ex. Nunc accumsan venenatis ipsum id sodales. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum
          primis in faucibus. Pellentesque eu viverra urna. Praesent ullamcorper aliquam lacus ac vestibulum. Donec efficitur efficitur purus, id venenatis nisl laoreet eu. Ut elit urna, faucibus in elit ac, scelerisque aliquam augue. Etiam blandit magna
          ut lectus porta feugiat nec pharetra arcu. Fusce massa turpis, eleifend volutpat erat sed, iaculis interdum nisl. Morbi lobortis tincidunt ex, id elementum nulla sollicitudin nec.
        </p>
        <p>
          Praesent interdum risus ligula, sed volutpat lacus aliquam sit amet. Quisque in dapibus augue. Maecenas ultricies, ipsum sit amet congue suscipit, neque mi vehicula mi, et auctor sapien diam vitae purus. Proin vitae tincidunt odio, at placerat tellus.
          Aenean fermentum libero vel nulla convallis egestas. Suspendisse porttitor orci ex, quis dapibus nibh accumsan sit amet. Curabitur imperdiet nec odio a feugiat. Suspendisse dui risus, dapibus id arcu vitae, varius hendrerit ipsum. Quisque vestibulum
          imperdiet venenatis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Duis laoreet sapien vel lacus molestie tempus. Phasellus eget feugiat tellus. Etiam tristique neque a aliquam commodo.
        </p>
        <p>
          Quisque ut velit laoreet, gravida dolor eget, congue risus. Vestibulum eget tortor at nisi blandit malesuada. Suspendisse mollis nunc ipsum, non fringilla lacus accumsan eu. Nullam vehicula mauris augue, non imperdiet lacus vestibulum a. Phasellus lacinia
          scelerisque nulla eu tempus. Cras varius augue turpis, sed hendrerit enim dignissim eget. Morbi elementum ante vel odio rhoncus molestie.
        </p>
        <p>
          Suspendisse sem metus, vulputate non justo eget, consectetur egestas enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas ac pretium lectus, non porttitor est. Duis quis suscipit arcu. Ut eget volutpat metus. Vivamus eget turpis aliquam, luctus est vitae, porttitor
          arcu. Nunc quis turpis id dui hendrerit convallis. Sed dictum pharetra est, eget malesuada ex vestibulum vel. Donec sit amet lacus a odio lobortis pretium sed ac ex. Suspendisse a scelerisque nisi, in convallis nibh. Ut ullamcorper, quam et
          aliquet dictum, dolor urna auctor metus, in varius odio urna in lorem. Pellentesque in felis sollicitudin, fringilla libero non, feugiat magna.
        </p>
        <p>
          Morbi consectetur ultricies nisl, ut commodo nunc. Vestibulum ultrices efficitur justo, vulputate fermentum risus vehicula id. Fusce in quam in elit ullamcorper convallis vitae et tellus. Maecenas at sollicitudin enim, nec iaculis enim. Phasellus tempus
          eros vitae mi feugiat, sit amet euismod mauris pharetra. Nam condimentum in mauris sit amet commodo. Donec lacinia, lectus eget rhoncus rutrum, augue orci gravida nibh, ut bibendum felis orci non eros. Nam hendrerit, tellus vitae tempus elementum,
          nibh urna ultrices neque, vitae tempor nulla risus quis enim. Suspendisse potenti. Cras convallis quis leo ac commodo. Donec eu nisi interdum, molestie urna eget, porta arcu. Quisque varius, nunc at consectetur vehicula, velit ligula tempor
          dolor, vitae vulputate odio diam id odio.
        </p>
        <p>
          Curabitur finibus odio erat, quis semper nibh tempor ut. Vestibulum congue id nibh sed rhoncus. Nulla eleifend lacus nisi. Aliquam in magna laoreet, ornare est faucibus, egestas quam. Fusce pretium mi non metus dapibus tempor a sed orci. Ut tempor nulla
          dui. Aenean commodo nunc nulla, sed accumsan libero mattis eget. Nunc finibus facilisis egestas. Praesent arcu nulla, rutrum sit amet arcu sed, sodales sodales velit. Fusce et magna justo. Aliquam tortor purus, convallis eget tempus quis, venenatis
          vitae turpis. Cras volutpat fringilla leo, nec blandit erat dapibus hendrerit. Curabitur tristique dolor non bibendum hendrerit.
        </p>
        <p>
          Integer in justo ut lectus elementum tempor eget at tellus. Nunc pretium tincidunt enim, et consectetur sapien tincidunt a. Praesent sed fermentum odio. Integer pulvinar purus tortor, finibus maximus nunc efficitur vel. Suspendisse potenti. Praesent vel
          arcu ut nisi laoreet ultricies. Nunc at molestie velit, a molestie elit. Quisque efficitur sed justo id imperdiet. Etiam pulvinar gravida purus ac pellentesque. Pellentesque a diam lorem.
        </p>
        <p>
          In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Morbi porta leo quis nibh tristique malesuada. Nullam nisl urna, viverra vulputate ultricies quis, placerat eu urna. Nunc ac sollicitudin mi. Nam gravida orci id tortor finibus, nec varius enim luctus. Etiam neque ex,
          condimentum a risus sit amet, convallis feugiat dui. Quisque gravida mauris sem, sed accumsan tellus volutpat vel. Fusce pellentesque porttitor interdum. In rutrum posuere risus at semper. Donec vel dui sed ipsum euismod vulputate.
        </p>
        <p>
          Vestibulum vehicula nisi non urna blandit, non euismod tortor sagittis. Ut tincidunt iaculis bibendum. Vestibulum vel nulla nunc. Etiam lobortis orci non facilisis pellentesque. Praesent commodo mi eu egestas cursus. Integer tincidunt hendrerit magna,
          vel convallis odio rhoncus facilisis. Praesent at posuere risus. Praesent massa orci, congue vel justo porttitor, blandit ullamcorper mi. Nulla eu laoreet dolor, vitae varius elit. Vivamus sagittis nisi dolor, tincidunt convallis quam eleifend
          a.
        </p>
        <p>
          Proin ligula leo, finibus eget hendrerit iaculis, lobortis sit amet urna. Aenean eget dignissim orci. Maecenas tincidunt, quam id laoreet hendrerit, lectus eros dapibus velit, sed pretium quam nisl quis urna. Ut vitae lorem sit amet augue elementum semper
          vel at lorem. Vivamus vitae molestie ante. In suscipit posuere ullamcorper. Donec viverra congue mauris, at dignissim eros facilisis nec. Curabitur tristique velit id nulla malesuada, eu gravida est fringilla. Nullam feugiat scelerisque porta.
        </p>
        <p>
          Nullam quis ullamcorper ante. Mauris non diam leo. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque non semper elit. Cras sed elit elementum, vehicula velit volutpat, lobortis mi. Cras tincidunt consequat scelerisque. Sed accumsan dictum
          ante, vel porttitor augue luctus quis. Donec risus justo, congue quis laoreet eu, finibus eu quam. Morbi in felis elit. Sed ac nulla gravida orci aliquam.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="generated">Generated 18 paragraphs, 1471 words, 10000 bytes of <a href="https://www.lipsum.com/" title="Lorem Ipsum">Lorem Ipsum</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <div class="boxed" style="overflow:visible !important;"><a style="text-decoration:none" href="mailto:help@lipsum.com">help@lipsum.com</a><br><a style="text-decoration:none" target="_blank" href="/privacy.pdf">Privacy Policy</a><a href="http://citenpl.internal.epo.org/wf/web/citenpl/citenpl.html?_url=https%3A//www.lipsum.com/privacy.pdf"
      class="btncitenpl citenpl" name="MIKELink" title="Cite this document: https://www.lipsum.com/privacy.pdf">CiteNPL<span class="doc">DOCS</span></a></div>



</div>
```